# How to represent two dimensional categorical data in a Bar Chart using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-science

I have a dataset which contains columns: 'Month', 'Category', and 'Profitability'. I used following to find the sum of 'Profitability' for each month and category.

```
q1=df.groupby(['Month','Category'])['Profitability'].sum()
```

Here is the result I got.

```
Month  Category   
1      Cosmetics       2685.9000
       First Aid       2128.0200
       Magazine         703.8900
       Supplements    37005.6200
       Toiletries      1893.0600
2      Cosmetics       2569.0600
       First Aid       3282.7850
       Magazine         679.1100
       Supplements    36647.8800
       Toiletries      1357.7500
3      Cosmetics       1350.7925
       First Aid       2238.3100
       Magazine         371.1200
       Supplements    21444.0900
       Toiletries      1226.1600
```

I want to represent them in a bar chart. What would be the best approach to visualize these categorical data?

Comment: What do you want your visualization to depict? - What do you want the viewer to see? What are you trying to highlight to the viewer? How about a stacked bar chart?- one bar for each category with the values from each month stacked ? Or do you want to show changes over time for each category?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585523/how-to-plot-categorical-and-continuous-data-in-pandas-matplotlib-seaborn/60585933?noredirect=1#comment107249497_60585933

Comment: Or maybe a bar for each month with the category values stacked?

Comment: @wwii I want to set Month in X axis and Profit in Y axis. Need to draw 5 bars for each month for each Month

Comment: A simple line graph is often preferable to a bar plot, especially if you want to show changes over time. You could use different colors to show the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preparatory step is to convert your DataFrame with a **single** column
and a MultiIndex into a DataFrame with "normal" index and a **separate**
column for each category:

```
df2 = df.Profitability.unstack()
```

Or if source of your data is a *Series* (not a *DataFrame*), then run:

```
df2 = q1.unstack()
```

The result, better fit as a figure source, is:

```
Category  Cosmetics  First Aid  Magazine  Supplements  Toiletries
Month                                                            
1         2685.9000   2128.020    703.89     37005.62     1893.06
2         2569.0600   3282.785    679.11     36647.88     1357.75
3         1350.7925   2238.310    371.12     21444.09     1226.16
```

​To draw the figure, the basic approach is to take **linear** scale of y axis.
The code to draw it is:

```
ax = df2.plot.bar(rot=0)
ax.get_figure().suptitle(t='Profitability', fontsize=20)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.35, 1.0));
```

The last instruction "moves" the legend a bit to the right (compared
to its default location), otherwise it would obscure some bars (try to draw
without this instruction).

The result is:

[image]

Note however that bars for *Suppelements* are very high, compared to
other categories, which are very low.

This is why I came up with the second solution, based on **logatithmic** scale
of *y* axis:

```
ax = df2.plot.bar(rot=0, logy=True)
ax.get_figure().suptitle(t='Profitability', fontsize=20)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.0))
yTicks = [1000, 3000, 10000, 30000]
yTickLabels = [ f'{i:,}' for i in yTicks ]
ax.set_yticks(yTicks)
ax.set_yticklabels(yTickLabels);
```

Last 4 instructions change the default ticks on *y* axis, as in my
opinion they are better readable that the default ticks (try to draw
a figure without these 4 lines for comparison).

The result is:

[image]

Now heigths of bars are easier to compare and *y* ticks are chosen roughly
on *tick(n-1) * 3* basis.

## Edit

If you want to have the legend **with a title**, add `title='Category'`
parameter to `ax.legend(...)` instruction, whichever of the above
solutions you choose.